# Power Dissipation

Tags: android, battery

I need to know the power dissipated at stant t from my android device!

**Power (P) = Voltage(V) * Current (I)**

I am able to get the value of Battery voltage through registering for an intent receiver to receive the Broadcast for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. But the problem is that Android does not
expose the value of current through this SDK interface.

Any suggestion / pointers for getting battery current value? Also
please correct me if I am wrong.

Deborah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not supported by the SDK but apparently it can be done by reading some values on the I2C bus.  Here is a link to the source of `CurrentWidget` which has found a method to read the current.  I'm seems the method of reading the current is different for each device.

http://code.google.com/p/currentwidget/source/browse/trunk/CurrentWidgetLibrary/src/com/manor/currentwidget/library/CurrentReaderFactory.java

good luck!

Comment: Nooooo! I read the code.. my device is HTC Hero and in my /sys/class/power_supply/battery there isn't this information, I know only temperature, voltage, level, status. :((((

Comment: you may have to do some I2C bus probing :[

Comment: why do you need the power dissipated anyway? if you don't mind me asking :]

Comment: I need it for my thesis: I have to monitor the energy consumption of some applications on the basis of a model of energy that requires instantaneous power